# How to getvalue after drag header coloumn

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm currently using JTable for display information and MODIFY them, but when I tried to `getValue()` from JTable after I dragged the header, I got value from previous changes (before I dragged it). How to make my JTable refresh/save any drag move? So I can implement the code in event such as `mouseRelease()` on the JTable.
[as you can see in the picture (already switch the header) that the value is '3', (it's suppose to be 'c' )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu16m.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of any of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjtable%5d%20When%20using%20a%20sorter%2c%20always%20remember%20to%20translate%20cell%20coordinates.): "always remember to translate cell coordinates."

Comment: [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)) and [`JTable#convertColumnIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel(int))

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks man, it works.

Comment: @trashgod Trust me, i already searched. I thought my problem is different. Mybad.